# Change automatic background colour of text box from grey to white (Field Template)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Using ASP.NET dynamic data (field template issue) - In a table in my DB a column was set to a 'bit' which was showing as a check box on screen.
I have used 'Field Templates' to change the tick box to a text box which displays yes or no depending on wether it is ticked or not:

In DB cs. file:

```
[UIHint("Yes_No_Boolean")]
public object Restricted_Hours { get; set; }
```

then:

```
public partial class BooleanField : System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl {
protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnDataBinding(e);

    object val = FieldValue;
    if ((bool)val == false)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "No";
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Yes";
    }
}

public override Control DataControl {
    get {
        return TextBox1;
    }
}
```

Only problem is now the textbox displays with a grey background. Does anyone know how to change it to a normal white back ground?

**EDIT**
I've just tried CheckBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; but there is no change

Comment: no one have any idea as to why this is happening, or how i can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry after some research i got it:

```
TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
TextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
TextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```